# How come my javascript does not work in facebook app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get a very simple javascript functionality to work in facebook app canvas, however, I am getting nowhere. I am posting the code below.

Also, I am only using a non-HTTPS canvas URL? Would that make any difference?

I am not able to get the facebookUserIDDiv innerHTML to change when I view my app on facebook.

However, when I go to the actual host URL (canvas URL), I am able to run any javascript without any issues.

Does FB app canvas even support standard DOM functions?

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    channelUrl:'//www.example.com/channel.html', 
    status:false, 
    cookie:true, 
    xfbml:false});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        if(response.status === "connected") {

            var facebookUserID = response.authResponse.userID;
            document.getElementById("facebookUserIDDiv").innerHTML 
            = facebookUserID;
        }

    }, true);

};

(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

</script>
<form>

    <div id="facebookUserIDDiv"/>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `status:false,` to `status:true,`. This `status` -

> check login status

Answer (score 0):

I was so sad. I even downed a full bottle of scotch. Life was falling apart...

I figured it out finally. I was really surprised as to why Facebook won't allow Javascript. Turned out I needed to make my canvas URL secure. So I uploaded the SSL certificate, and updated the Facebook app dashboard with the secure canvas URL.

Also make sure any you don't specify http:// or https:// while requesting content. Just specify //, and the right protocol will be used for the request. Which means, if the page was requested as a secure page, then any additional resources requested from within the page, will automatically be requested as https. And if the page was requested using just http, then the same resources requested from within the page will be requested using http protocol automatically.